# Flutter: How to change the state of a variable in another dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on an app; I want to change the value of a String which is declared in another dart file and then pass that changed state to the stateful widget.

I.E;

1. I create a file called as "Body.dart" file where I have declared a String called as 'scale' who's value initially is "Empty".
2. Later when a button in another dart file "scale_button" is pressed, I want to assign the string scale = "Hello" in my Body.dart file. So that the stateful widget also displays the same on the screen.

Comment: Share samples of your code.

Comment: This is global state management, if you didn't get to research anything then I believe that this [flutter doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `provider`(or any other state management) package in that case. In `yaml` file add, `provider: ^4.3.2+4`

```dart
class HomeApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeAppState createState() => _HomeAppState();
}

class _HomeAppState extends State<HomeApp> {
  StringProvider _stringProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stringProvider = Provider.of<StringProvider>(context, listen: false);
  }

  void updateString() {
    _stringProvider.setString('hai');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    StringProvider _stringProvider = Provider.of<StringProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                _stringProvider.str,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: updateString,
              child: Text('Click'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// class for storing data(StringProvider.dart)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StringProvider extends ChangeNotifier { // create a common file for data
  String _str = 'hello';

  String get str => _str;

  void setString(String st) {
    _str = st;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Balaji, Thank you for providing the code for integer. But can you please tell me how to do the same with string. I want to be able to change the string value when a button is pressed.

Comment: @AkellaNiranjan I have updated the code for the string. Let me know if that works

Comment: Hello Balaji, I want to do the "_stringProvider.setString('hai')" in a different dart file. The code which you have given above is only working if I try to set the new string in the same dart file. But instead I would like to set the new string in a different dart file.

Comment: @AkellaNiranjan you have to use this kind of approach only and you can refer the value wherever wanted and also you change the value wherever you wanted.You can follow the same approach

Comment: Venkataraman, Could you also help me with one more thing, Do you know how to generate sound in flutter app. Like I am currently working on a musical app like "Tanpura". Could you please tell me how can I generate my own sound of various frequencies in flutter.

Comment: Sure I will do that. Please accept my answer and upvote as well if that helped you

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new Flutter project the sample code of the counter shows you how to do this. Check out the comments in the next code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // here is passing a String to MyHomePage.
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // And here you can see how to make the widget wait for a variable 
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Full code of Sample Counter App

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not work please provider full code

Comment: Belaji, you just need to open Android Studio o VS code and create a new flutter project, when you create a new project, it cames with a counter app example, the code I put is from there,

Comment: @FerBueroTrebino Your solution only works if I am changing the value in the same dart file. But what I need is that I want to change the value of a string in a different dart file and it should reflect in the present dart file.

Comment: @FerBueroTrebino I understood that it comes as a flutter sample when creating a flutter app.The Thing is if you are answering here it should be clear and helpful

Comment: @AkellaNiranjan I was trying to help you to achieve it with a simple explanation, but the correct answer was given by JustCase yesterday. "This is global state management, if you didn't get to research anything then I believe that this flutter doc should help you."

Comment: You can achieve this with a package like Provider, as Balaji said. Also, you can search and try another state management package, there is a lot, but the official recommendation is to use Provider.